# Bash Directory Flattening and Renaming

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have the following folder structure...

```
/main/2000/01_January/a.jpg
/main/2000/01_January/b.jpg
/main/2000/04_April/a.jpg
/main/2000/04_April/b.jpg
/main/2000/04_April/c.jpg
/main/2001/02_February/a.jpg
/main/2002/06_June/a.jpg
```

etc...

I need a bash script to flatten this structure out in the following manner. I want to eliminate the second level folders (2000, 2001, 2002, etc) and rename the third level folder by inserting the second level folder name and truncating the '_*monthname*'. The result should look like this...

```
/main/2000-01/a.jpg
/main/2000-01/b.jpg
/main/2000-04/a.jpg
/main/2000-04/b.jpg
/main/2000-04/c.jpg
/main/2001-02/a.jpg
/main/2002-06/a.jpg
```

etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
x='/main/2000/01_January/a.jpg'
a=( $(IFS=/ read -a a <<< "$x" && echo ${a[@]}) )
y=$(printf "/%s/%s-%s/%s" ${a[0]} ${a[1]} ${a[2]/_*/} ${a[3]})
echo "$y"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
/main/2000-01/a.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /main/????/[0-9][0-9]_*/ -type f | while read -r FILE; do
    DEST=${FILE:0:10}-${FILE:11:2}/
    echo "Moving $FILE to $DEST."
    mkdir -p "$DEST" && mv "$FILE" "$DEST"
done

# rm -fr /main/????/
```